# How to do report like a Treelist

Tags: devexpress, grouping, reporting, treelist

Hello everyone I have a question about Devexpress Report.I wanna that I have a report and and treelist.Can i make that report like treelist? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Can i embed a treelist to report in c# Devexpress ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PrintableComponentContainer control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/clsDevExpressXtraReportsUIPrintableComponentContainertopic) to embed a TreeList into an XtraReport.